# ZF2 Form / Doctrine ManyToMany Self Referring Relation

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, self-reference

When I try to create ZF2 Form with Doctrine self referencing relation I get Doctrine error `Method "Status::getName" is not callable`

Below my YAML configuration for my entity:

```
Status:
  type: entity
  table: status
  fields:
    id:
      id: true
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
      options:
        unsigned: true
    name:
     type: string
     length: 255
  manyToMany:
    workflow:
      targetEntity: Status
      joinTable:
        name: status_workflow
        joinColumns:
          statusId:
            referencedColumnName: id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          nextStatusId:
            referencedColumnName: id
```

and form

```
class WorkflowForm extends Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setName('workflow');

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'workflow',
            'type' => WorkflowFieldset::class,
            'options' => [
                'use_as_base_fieldset' => true,
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

and fieldset

```
class WorkflowFieldset extends Fieldset ObjectManagerAwareInterface
{
    use ProvidesObjectManager;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->setName('workflow');

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'id',
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Status name'
            ],
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'workflow',
            'type' => ObjectSelect::class,
            'attributes' => [
                'multiple' => true,
            ],
            'options' => [
                'object_manager' => $this->getObjectManager(),
                'target_class' => Status::class,
                'property' => 'name',
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

and action

```
public function workflowEditAction()
{
    $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $fm = $sm->get('FormElementManager');
    $om = $sm->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

    $form = $fm->get(WorkflowForm::class);
    //$workflow = $om->getRepository(Status::class)->getStatusesByEntityId($route->getParam('id'));
    //$form->bind($workflow);

    return new ViewModel([
        'form' => $form,
    ]);
}
```

Finally I want get something like this

[image]

Sorry for so much code as not to inflate even more, I did not show Hidrator, Factory and template.

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After day of searching I solved my problem. The main thing is that need generate array to populate form.

I create array with next structure

```
$values = array(4) {
  [0] => array(9) {
    ["id"] => int(99)
    ["name"] => string(6) "active"
    ["entityId"] => int(30)
    ["workflow"] => array(2) {
      [0] => int(100)
      [1] => int(101)
    }
  }
  [1] => array(9) {
    ["id"] => int(100)
    ["name"] => string(8) "inactive"
    ["entityId"] => int(30)
    ["workflow"] => array(0) {
    }
  }
  [2] => array(9) {
    ["id"] => int(101)
    ["name"] => string(6) "paused"
    ["entityId"] => int(30)
    ["workflow"] => array(1) {
      [0] => int(99)
    }
  }
}
```

And populate form `$form->populateValues(['statuses' => $values]);`

Next need create custom method in repository

```
public function getWorkflowByModule($module) {
    $moduleAlias = 'entity';
    $workflowAlias = 'workflow';
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder($this->_alias)
        ->select($this->_alias)
        ->leftJoin($this->_alias . '.workflow', $workflowAlias)
        ->leftJoin($this->_alias . '.entity', $moduleAlias);
    $qb->where($qb->expr()->eq($this->_alias . '.' . 'entity', $module->getId()));

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Change select in Fieldset

```
$this->add([
        'name' => 'workflow',
        'type' => ObjectSelect::class,
        'attributes' => [
            'multiple' => true,
        ],
        'options' => [
            'object_manager' => $this->getObjectManager(),
            'target_class' => Status::class,
            'property' => 'name',
            'is_method' => true,
            'find_method' => [
                'name' => 'getWorkflowByModule',
                'params' => [
                    'module' => $this->getModule(),
                ],
            ], 
        ],
    ]);
```

Result is what I expected

[image]